# Multi-threaded evaluation of lazy generator in Python(3.x) for brute-forcing

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, brute-force

What is a good way to parallelize generating each element of a lazy generator and running some (cpu-bound) evaluation function on it? I do not need a map of the evaluation function on each element, just one single result where the condition is met. There are a lot of examples for the multiprocessing module, but I can't figure out how to apply this to my problem.

Example:

I have a lazy generator for key candidates which I want to test against an evaluation function that determines if the key, combined with some message, produces the expected output when run through some cryptographic algorithm.

The example code below takes 53s on my machine to run worker(keySpace). I would like to spawn *cpu_count* threads to do this in parallel to shorten the time by roughly *1/cpu_count*. All threads can be stopped once one of the workers returns. The size of the keySpace is known beforehand, and it would be nice to sporadically report back the current progress from each thread.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from struct import pack
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from time import sleep

#all keys from b'\x00\x00\x00\x00' to b'xff\xff\xff\x00'
keySpaceSize = 2**24
keySpace = map(lambda x: pack("<I", x), range(keySpaceSize))

#the ciphertext is 'HelloWorld' xor'd with 'ABC\0'
knownPlaintext = b'HelloWorld'
ciphertext = b"\t'/l.\x15,r-&"

#lets use xor encryption as an example
def someSymmetricAlgorithm(key, message):
    return bytes((int(k) ^ int(m) for (k, m) in zip(cycle(key), message)))

#returns the given key when it produces the known plaintext from the ciphertext
def testKey(key):
    plaintext = someSymmetricAlgorithm(key, ciphertext)
    if plaintext == knownPlaintext:
        return key

#tests each element of an iterable
def worker(KeySpaceSlice):
    for key in KeySpaceSlice:
        result = testKey(key)
        if result:
            return result

start = timer()

#how to parallelize this?
result = worker(keySpace)

elapsed = timer() - start

if result:
    print("found key: %s in %f seconds" % (result, elapsed))
```

Side question:

Initially, I thought I would just itertools.islice the generator and use Pool.imap. But unexpectedly, even with chunksize=keySpaceSize/poolSize, it seems to be spawning a process for each evaluation. Am I misunderstanding the meaning of 'chunksize'? I thought it would just create a thread for each chunk.

Environment:

```
Python 3.4.2 (v3.4.2:ab2c023a9432, Oct  6 2014, 22:15:05) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

I'd like a threaded solution to also work on linux.

Comment: If the generator is deterministic, maybe you could give it parameters to let you start it from a given intermediate value?

Comment: Certainly. But building the generator like this is much more complicated than islice(iterator=keypace, start=cpu, end=none, step=num_cpu), thus passing elements to each thread in a round-robin fashion. And it does not solve the general problem, which is passing the actual elements to the threads.